# multiple file upload not working in yii2

Tags: yii2

multiple file not uploaded using yii2,data are not saved into database.It showing this error htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.

Myform:

```
  echo $form->field($model, 'product_img[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true]);
```

Model:

```
   {
    return [

   [['product_img'],'file', 'maxFiles' => 2],
    ];
}
```

Controller :

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Product();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {

         $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'product_img');
        foreach ($model->file as $file) {

        $model2 = new Product();

        $model2->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
         $model2->product_img='uploads/' . $file;


        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `product`(`p_id`, `category`, `sub_category`, `product_img`, `product_name`) VALUES (Null,"'.($model2->category).'","'.($model2->sub_category).'","'.($model2->product_img).'","'.($model2->product_name).'")';
        $command = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql);
        $command->execute();
            $file->saveAs('uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);

        }
              return $this->render('view', [
                'model' => $model,
                ]);

    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Yii2 upload multiple files](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html#uploading-multiple-files)

Comment: its not working for me.

Comment: @IlakkiyaM Posted an answer . Please check if its working

Comment: see how to save model, no need for **insert query**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following line in your controller action is wrong

```
$model2->product_img='uploads/' . $file;
```

`$file` is an object not string

You may need to change that line to

```
$model2->product_img = 'uploads/' .$file->baseName;
```

or if you intend to access the file later using this column

```
$model2->product_img = 'uploads/' .$file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
```